# PHP - Reading contents of shared network directory

Tags: php

I have a website that needs to read and get files from a local network directory:

The linux box hosting my site is on a vhost.

Outside of that, I have a directory that I need to read -- I can access the directory from my computer by typing in the path in my browser like so:

file://pathd/to/files/here/

This will show the contents in my browser. But I'm not sure of the best way to make this readable from within my PHP website that's in the VM

I have tried:

```
$isFolder = is_dir("file://pathd/to/files/here/");
var_dump($isFolder); 
// this shows false
```

Would I need to be making a curl request? A bit lost here:

Thanks

Comment: Where are the files? On the server, or your computer? If it's on the server, then it can't go reading files from your computer!

Comment: `is_dir()` expects an actual local directory. In order to use it to access a network share, you'll need to have that share mounted on the server.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol How would I go about reading files from the server?

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through a remote directory this way, you'll need to localize the filesystem. The most common way, in my experience, would be to mount the network drive on your web server with a privileged user. If you aren't able to do that and have go to over the network, you'll need some sort of service (SFTP, SSH, an API, etc) to handle the responses. To my knowledge, there isn't really a way to traverse a file system not local to the server, short of passing commands via SSH or a custom API.

Hopefully that helps, if you do want to look into mounting the directory, Samba is a good option on Linux. Otherwise, PHP has the ability to handle the SFTP, SSH requests, you'd just have to write that code.

Comment: What if I were to just need to reference a file (like a PDF file) from the remote directory? Is something like that possible?

Comment: If it's available via a web server you could make a curl request for it; but as far as being able to read it from the remote directory directly, I'm not aware of any good way to do that with out some service or mounted network storage in between. I have experience using mounted network drives to accomplish something similar, and while it's not perfect, it was definitely workable. That would be my recommendation, personally (with proper security in place).

Comment: I managed to mount the drive. But what would I do from here? I can see the directories in the drive, but if I try to 'cd' into them, I get "Invalid Argument"